# Running out of Time in War while Attacking

Tags: clash-of-clans

It is rarely if not nearly impossible to be in a middle of a war battle when the war time ends. For example, let's assume I start an attack against a base with only 1 minute and 30 seconds of war time left. I use an quick, 3-star gaining strategy for sake of time but while I am still attacking, the war has "ended".

In this case (attack strategy will vary), will the battle continue, ending the war as soon as the attack is complete or will it stop my attack and force a surrender?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You will have the full 3 minutes to perform your attack if you start your attack with at least 1 second left on the war clock.  It will not stop your attack and force a surrender as long as you do so.**

However, once the war clock reaches 0, no new attacks can take place and the war will end once the final attacks are completed.

Source: I have done this before a few times, lost to this a few times, [forums,](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/273281-Q-What-happens-if-attack-is-in-progress-when-the-clan-war-ends) and [here is a youtube clip of this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9xhGxZmhsJA).

[image]

(screenshot is from the youtube clip linked above)